# Block access to any directory of a certain name

Tags: windows, security, iis, iis-7

Is it possible in IIS to block access to any directory in the public web folder, that has a certain name. For example `private_cms`?

If possible, is there any performance penalty to this? Would it be better to store the files outside of the www folder?

Comment: what do you mean block the access? from the users on the server to access in windows explorer? or from web users to access through url?

Comment: Web access. The .Net application will still need filesystem access to the file, but there should be no direct access to the files via the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your directory to the "request filter" in IIS:

sorry I use Chinese version of windows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Windows Explorer remove permissions for the IIS user to read from that folder.